# D flip-flop in Cadence

Tags: flipflop, cmos, vlsi, cadence

[image]

I am designing a D flip-flop. While doing my pre-layout simulations, I wasn't getting the output Q for the inputs, see attachments.

But when I tried to take the output from CLKPULSE, I was getting some zigzag signals.

Can you share your thoughts on this?

Using Cadence environment, TSMC 180nm Tech

[image: Output Waveforms]

[image: Schematic Diagram]

Comment: Is there RTL associated with this?  or, maybe, is this a structural sim... either way is this written in Verilog/VHDL?

Comment: Verilog-A?  I am out on this (but, I wish I knew more about Verilog-A) :/  Check/post on Mentor's verficationacademy.com

Comment: All the D-FF's I have seen look rather different. Using two sets of "feed-back inverters" and transmission gates: https://allthingsvlsi.wordpress.coma/tag/transmission-gate-based-d-flip-flop/

Answer (score 1):

1. @CapnJJ I believe it is custom design with 0.18um.
2. @Vinay: First of all you need to run realistic simulations. Find ft of your technology. Now find 0.2ft. Set the rise and fall time accordingly for input signals. A realistic input signal is shown in 3 below.
3. [A Non-overlapping two-phase clock generator
   with adjustable duty cycle](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/776a/1914a21f9a48945e78961c56e94fca09da67.pdf)
4. DETFF, [The Usage of Dual Edge Triggered Flip-flops
   in Low Power, Low Voltage Applications](https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~cdr/pubs/wai_masc.pdf)
5. More helpful, [Low power dual edge - Triggered static
   D flip-flop](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1307/1307.3075.pdf)
6. All the sizes in your schematics are pw, nw and rw. I think you can read up more about analog design before attempting tape out.